# .htaccess конфиг

Tags: .htaccess

Помогите с написанием конфига.
есть ссылка site.ru/qwerty.htm 
нужно чтобы отсылало на site.ru/qwerty

Comment: Вопрос не понятен, может восприниматься двояко, перефразируйте и распишите точнее чего вы хотите.

Answer (score 1):

```
Redirect /qwerty.htm http://site.ru/qwerty
```